# Using the Perl split() command to parse the output from the `du' command

Tags: linux, perl, split, du

I have a Perl script that has the following snippet in it:

```
@mylittlearray = split(/\/dir1\/dir2\//, `du --max-depth=1 \/dir1\/dir2\//`
print $mylittlearray[0];
print $mylittlearray[1];
print "\n";
```

The output is

```
24    ones
8
```

mylittlearray[0] and [1] should be returning only 24  and *"ones"*, not *"ones8"*.  If I pipe the du command to a file and turn on set list in VIM I see the following:

```
24^I./ones$
8^I./twos$
```

If I run the `du` command with a `-0`, I see this:

```
24      ./ones^@8       ./twos^@8       ./threes^@8     ./fours^@8      ./fives^@80     .^@
```

I'm trying to figure out how to split either format so that directory names are separated or split from the size for the next directory.  In other words I want mylittlearray[0] to equal 24, mylittlearray[1] to only contain *"ones"*, mylittlearray[2] would contain *"8"* and so on.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: can you tell me how to get result "24" and not "24   ones" ?
|xargs {'print $1'} is also not working

Comment: i got it :D
i have to give |xargs {'print \$1'}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question doesn't quite make it clear, but if you're simply interested in gathering the data for each resulting entry from `du`, loop over the results like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Capture the output from du
my @array = `du --max-depth=1 /some/folder/`;

# Loop over the output
foreach (@array)
{
    chomp; # Strip new-line
    my ($size, $dir) = split; # Split on whitespace
    print "Dir: $dir, Size: $size\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `map` instead of `split`:

```
my $dir = "/dir1/dir2/";
my @mylittlearray = map { m!(\d+)\s+$dir(.*)! } `du --max-depth=1 '$dir'`;
print join(", ", @mylittlearray), "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks folks, for the help.  I ended up with a different solution but definitely appreciate the feedback.